# Read REG_RESOURCE_LIST memory values - Incorrect value

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry, regedit

I am trying to read the physical memory values in `Hardware\ResourceMap\System Resources\Physical Memory` using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    LPCTSTR pszSubKey = L"Hardware\\ResourceMap\\System Resources\\Physical Memory";
    LPCTSTR pszValueName = L".Translated";

    if (! RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pszSubKey, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "RegOpenKey failed" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD dwType = 0;
    LPBYTE lpData = NULL;
    DWORD dwLength = 0;

    if (! RegQueryValueEx(hKey, pszValueName, 0, &dwType, NULL, &dwLength) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "RegOpenKey failed" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    lpData = new BYTE[dwLength];
    RegQueryValueEx(hKey, pszValueName, 0, &dwType, lpData, &dwLength);
    RegCloseKey(hKey);

    DWORD dwResourceCount = *(DWORD*)(lpData + 16);

    auto pmi = lpData + 24;

    for (int dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < dwResourceCount; dwIndex++)
    {
        auto start = *(uint64_t*)(pmi + 0);
        cout << "-> 0x" << hex << start;

        auto length = *(uint64_t*)(pmi + 8);
        cout << "\t + 0x" << hex << length;

        auto endaddr = start + length;
        cout << "\t0x" << hex << endaddr << endl;

        pmi += 20;
    }

    delete[]lpData;
}
```

A sample output:

```
-> 0x1000        + 0x57000      0x58000
-> 0x59000       + 0x46000      0x9f000
-> 0x100000      + 0xc855f000   0xc865f000
-> 0xc8666000    + 0xbf3000     0xc9259000
-> 0xc9759000    + 0x13779000   0xdced2000
-> 0xdd0d8000    + 0x3c000      0xdd114000
-> 0xddfff000    + 0x1000       0xde000000
-> 0x100000000   + 0x41f0000    0x1041f0000
```

The problem is that the last length value is incorrect.

Instead of `0x41f0000`, the Registry editor shows `0x41f000000` to be the correct value:

[image: regedit_value.jpg]

I have been researching this issue for the past few days, but cannot figure out why I get a false value here.

Can anyone with more experience using the Win32 API help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if value type is `REG_RESOURCE_LIST` value data is [`CM_RESOURCE_LIST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_cm_resource_list) structure. need use it instead of `*(DWORD*)(lpData + 16);`, `lpData + 24`. anyway your code is incorrect in case `Count` != 1. what you try print is [`CM_PARTIAL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_cm_partial_resource_descriptor) structures. but you not check the `Type` member of `CM_PARTIAL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR`. but it cab be different. can be `CmResourceTypeMemory` but also can be `CmResourceTypeMemoryLarge` - you not take this in account. in case `CmResourceTypeMemoryLarge` need check `Flags` for

```
CM_RESOURCE_MEMORY_LARGE_40
CM_RESOURCE_MEMORY_LARGE_48
CM_RESOURCE_MEMORY_LARGE_64
```

and

[image]

you say:

> Instead of 0x41f0000 the regeditor shows 0x41f000000

but `0x41f000000` is shifted on 8 bit `0x41f0000`. based on this obvious that you really have here `CmResourceTypeMemoryLarge` with `CM_RESOURCE_MEMORY_40` flag.

in this case need use **Length40** member:

> The high 32 bits of the 40-bit length, in bytes, of the range of
>   allocated memory addresses. The lowest 8 bits are treated as zero.

so code for dump `CM_RESOURCE_LIST` must be next:

```
BOOL Memory(PCM_RESOURCE_LIST pcrl, ULONG size)
{
    if (size < FIELD_OFFSET(CM_RESOURCE_LIST, List))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    size -= FIELD_OFFSET(CM_RESOURCE_LIST, List);

    if (ULONG Count = pcrl->Count)
    {
        PCM_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR List = pcrl->List;

        do 
        {
            if (size < FIELD_OFFSET(CM_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR, PartialResourceList.PartialDescriptors))
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            size -= FIELD_OFFSET(CM_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR, PartialResourceList.PartialDescriptors);

            DbgPrint("InterfaceType=%x BusNumber=%u\n", List->InterfaceType, List->BusNumber);

            if (ULONG n = List->PartialResourceList.Count)
            {
                PCM_PARTIAL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR PartialDescriptors = List->PartialResourceList.PartialDescriptors;

                do 
                {
                    if (size < sizeof(CM_PARTIAL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR))
                    {
                        return FALSE;
                    }

                    size -= sizeof(CM_PARTIAL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR);

                    ULONG64 Length = PartialDescriptors->u.Memory.Length;

                    switch (PartialDescriptors->Type)
                    {
                    case CmResourceTypeMemoryLarge:

                        switch (PartialDescriptors->Flags & (CM_RESOURCE_MEMORY_LARGE_40|
                            CM_RESOURCE_MEMORY_LARGE_48|CM_RESOURCE_MEMORY_LARGE_64))
                        {
                        case CM_RESOURCE_MEMORY_LARGE_40:
                            Length <<= 8;
                            break;
                        case CM_RESOURCE_MEMORY_LARGE_48:
                            Length <<= 16;
                            break;
                        case CM_RESOURCE_MEMORY_LARGE_64:
                            Length <<= 32;
                            break;
                        default:
                            DbgPrint("unknown mamory type\n");
                            continue;
                        }
                    case CmResourceTypeMemory:
                        DbgPrint("%016I64x %I64x\n", 
                            PartialDescriptors->u.Memory.Start.QuadPart, Length);
                        break;
                    }

                } while (PartialDescriptors++, --n);
            }

        } while (List++, --Count);
    }

    return size == 0;
}
```

also when we get it data - need not forget close key handle even on error (you not do this when `RegQueryValueEx` fail) and use `RegOpenKeyExW` instead `RegOpenKey` for ability specify the desired access rights to the key. the use 2 sequential calls to `RegQueryValueEx` (with 0 buffer and allocated once buffer) also not the best. because in theory buffer size can changed (some change value) between this 2 calls and you can fail got data on second call `RegQueryValueEx`too. also we can already on first call allocate reasonable memory space, and only if it will be not enough - reallocate on next call. so better call this in loop until we got `ERROR_MORE_DATA` and first time call with already not empty buffer:

```
ULONG Memory()
{
    HKEY hKey;

    ULONG dwError = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
        L"Hardware\\ResourceMap\\System Resources\\Physical Memory", 
        0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

    if (dwError == NOERROR)
    {
        ULONG cb = 0x100;

        do 
        {
            dwError = ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES;

            union {
                PVOID buf;
                PBYTE pb;
                PCM_RESOURCE_LIST pcrl;
            };

            if (buf = LocalAlloc(0, cb))
            {
                ULONG dwType;

                if ((dwError = RegQueryValueExW(hKey, L".Translated", 
                    0, &dwType, pb, &cb)) == NOERROR)
                {
                    if (dwType == REG_RESOURCE_LIST)
                    {
                        if (!Memory(pcrl, cb))
                        {
                            DbgPrint("error parsing resource list\n");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dwError = ERROR_INVALID_DATATYPE;
                    }
                }

                LocalFree(buf);
            }

        } while (dwError == ERROR_MORE_DATA);

        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    return dwError;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Am I correct that only the length values have to be shifted and not the start addresses?

Comment: @Thomas - yes, only length, the start address already 64bit value